# How to bidding background and image source in ListView correspond to given properties - WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, listview

I have to show the list of printer and point out which of it is connected or is being used. If the printer is online, the background colour is Aqua, else the background turn to red. And if the printer is being used, the image will be showed correspond to image sources.

```
public class Printer
    {
        string sPrinterName;
        bool bIsOnline;
        bool bIsUsing;

        public string Name
        {
            get { return sPrinterName; }
            set { sPrinterName = value; }
        }

        public bool IsOnline
        {
            get { return bIsOnline; }
            set { bIsOnline = value; }
        }

        public bool IsUsing
        {
            get { return bIsUsing; }
            set { bIsUsing = value; }
        }

        public Printer()
        {
            sPrinterName = "";
            bIsOnline = false;
            bIsUsing = false;
        }
    }
```

I use ListView to show list of printer, here is my xaml:

```
<ListView Margin="25,100,25,25" Name="lvPrinters"  BorderThickness="0" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
        <ListView.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <WrapPanel Width="640" ItemWidth="160" ItemHeight="160"></WrapPanel>
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemsPanel>
        <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
                <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch"></Setter>
                <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0"/>
                <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0,15,15,0"/>
                <Setter Property="Padding" Value="5"/>
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="Aqua"></Setter>
            </Style>
        </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="1*"/>
                        <RowDefinition Height="2*" />
                        <RowDefinition Height="1*" />
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                    <TextBlock Text="Printer: " Grid.Row="0"/>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"  Grid.Row="1" FontWeight="Bold" TextWrapping="Wrap"/>                   
                    <Image Width="30" Grid.Row="2">
                        <Image.Source>
                            <BitmapImage DecodePixelWidth="30" UriSource="bindding value" />
                        </Image.Source>
                    </Image>
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
```

Here is my C# code:

```
private void OrderPrinter_Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            lits_Printer = new List<Printer>();

            for (int i = 1; i < 9; i++)
            {
                Printer myPrinter = new Printer();
                myPrinter.Name = "Printer " + i.ToString();                
                myPrinter.IsOnline = true;
                myPrinter.IsUsing = false;
                lits_Printer.Add(myPrinter);
            }

            lits_Printer[0].IsOnline = false;
            lits_Printer[3].IsUsing = true;

            lvPrinters.ItemsSource = lits_Printer;
        }
```

My expected result is look like that [My expected result](https://app.box.com/s/kzicc2lioevad7dkh3af)

But I don't know how to bidding background of ListViewItem and UriSource of Image correspond to IsOnline and IsUsing properties of printer object, please help me to do that, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I finally found the solution for my issue, just use ValueConverters. Here is useful example link about ValueConverters [wpf-tutorial-binding-converters](http://tech.pro/tutorial/806/wpf-tutorial-binding-converters)